# Who is the caller of onreadystatechange when javascript is single-threaded?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Well, i am new to javascript and heard it is single-threaded. In my mind if you make an asynchronous request, it should start an own thread which controls if the server already responded. This won't work in Javascript. I am thinking is there some built-in mechanism which  saves all listeners and calls them, depending on conditions they have "agreed" to (onreadystatechange).

This is just an assumption and I guess i am totally wrong. Well, maybe somebody can help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the javascript execution itself is single-threaded, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11660429/1048572). Yet, the underlying engine might use more threads.

So, the HTTP request (created somewhere deep in the bowels of the browser) might have its own thread, but when something (like a response) happens, it will fire an event to be queued into the JS task scheduler. As soon as the current script execution has ended, the `onreadystatechange` function will be called.

Answer (score 2):

As you know the XHR object is different for all browsers. For example IE uses an ActiveX, FF uses the XMLHttpRequest object, ... There are some efforts to unify this in HTML5 by introducing the [XHR2 object](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) but it's still not widely supported. So this will be implemented differently for each browser. Some might use threads, others something else. That's not pure javascript. When people are saying that javascript is single threaded they mean that you cannot create threads manually in javascript. But this doesn't mean that you cannot do asynchronous programming.